Example of a PID in which $SL_n \neq E_n$
In lectures on algebra, the fact was proved using simple methods that if $R$ is a Euclidean ring, then $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(R) = \mathrm{E}_n(R)$, where $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(R) = \{m \in \mathrm{M}_{n \times n}(R) \space | \space \Delta m = 1\}$, $\mathrm{E}_n (R) = \langle t_{i j}(\lambda) \space | \space i \neq j, i, j \in \{1, ..., n\}, \lambda \in R \rangle$. At the same lecture, it was said that this is generally incorrect for PID.
Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience to answer this question, but I want to make sure of the fact expressed by the teacher. Can you give a counterexample?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

This might have to do with Algebraic K theory. Perhaps the book of Milnor could help?

I assume $\Delta$ is the determinant from the notation, is $t_{ij}(\lambda)$ the matrix with entry $\lambda$ at the $(i, j)$ slot and $1$s on the diagonal? Do you exclude $i = j$ so that this matrix is actually in $\mathrm{SL}_n$?

After search and jump,  this is answered in Paul M. Cohn's paper:

Theorem (Theorem 1.1 or Theorem 6.I): Let $\mathcal O_D$ be the integer ring of $\Bbb Q( \sqrt{-D} )$, where $D$ is a square free integer and $D\not=1, 2, 3, 7, 11$, then $SL_2(\mathcal O_D)$ is not generated by elementary matrices.

In particular, when $D=19$, $\mathcal O_D=\Bbb Z[\theta]$ is a PID but not an Euclidean domain (cf. this question), where $\theta = \frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}$ with minimal polynomial $\theta^2-\theta+5=0$.
On Page 23, Cohn commented that the following matrix cannot be generated by elementary matrices.
$$\begin{pmatrix} 3-\theta & 2+\theta \\ -3-2\theta & 5-2\theta \end{pmatrix}$$
